# how to get values of my radio button and display it in my update form?

Tags: java, jsp

i do jsp application and i have form who add evaluation in my jsp ListEvaluation.jsp
when i click on update button i want to display the value of my ListEvaluation in my updateform

here is what i do... its work for the input text but not for the button radio, select and date

```
  <form id="form" method="post" action="/Labo2/ModifierServlet">
    <div class="formulaire">
        <h4>Formulaire pour modifier une évaluation</h4>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Numéro</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" value="<%=e.getNumero()%>" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Nom</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value="<%=e.getNom()%>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Prénom</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" value="<%=e.getPrenom()%>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Téléphone</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="<%=e.getTelephone()%>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Courriel</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="courriel" name="courriel" value="<%=e.getCourriel()%>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Sexe</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">

                <input type="radio" value="F" id="sexe" name="sexe" />F
                <input type="radio" value="M" id="sexe" name="sexe"/>M
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Note</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="note" name="note" value="<%=e.getNote()%>">
                    <option value=" ">  </option>
                    <option value="tres bien">Trés bien</option>
                    <option value="bien">bien</option>
                    <option value="moyen">moyen</option>
                    <option value="mediocre">Médiocre</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Date d'évaluation</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="<%=e.getDateEvaluation()%>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Commentaire</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea id=commentaires" name="commentaires" value="<%=e.getCommentaire()%>"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="butn" />
                <input type="reset" value="Effacer" class="butn" />
                <button class="butn">Retour à la liste</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

how can i get values of my radio button and select? 
thank you

Comment: Once you submit your form it is handled by the ```ModifierServlet```. In the servlet's code you can use the ```request.getParameter('sexe')```to retrieve the value of your radio. Then you need to pass it as a request attribute to the jsp to which you are forwarding.

Comment: thank you 
i will try :)